# no repeat myself, smart loop with objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps-api-3

Here is what I created **[jsfiddle Sample](http://jsfiddle.net/ZxmX7/3/)** multiple maps on a same single page.

I pretty much "repeat" myself at all times as this way is a little bit easier for myself to read, my JavaScript skill is just a little bit better than a beginner, still learning.

I know I can create an object like

```
var maps ={
    ['latlng', 48.89376,2.33742],
    ['latlng1', 40.73717,-73.9],
    ['latlng2', -8.79069, 115.15927],
}
```

to make life easier. but I dont know how to make objects to work.

here is my code

```
function initialize() {
        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(48.89376,2.33742); //1 location
        var latlng1 = new google.maps.LatLng(40.73717,-73.98439); //2 location
        var latlng2 = new google.maps.LatLng(-8.79069, 115.15927); //3 location

        var settings = {
            zoom: 15,
            center: latlng,
            disableDefaultUI: true,
            zoomControl: true,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
         var settings1 = {
            zoom: 15,
            center: latlng1,
            disableDefaultUI: true,
            zoomControl: true,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };

       var settings2 = {
            zoom: 15,
            center: latlng2,
            disableDefaultUI: true,
            zoomControl: true,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), settings);
        var map1 = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map1"), settings1);
        var map2 = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map2"), settings2);

        var marker=new google.maps.Marker({
              position:latlng,
              });
         marker.setMap(map);

         var marker1 =  new google.maps.Marker({
              position:latlng1,
              });
         marker1.setMap(map1);

        var marker2 =  new google.maps.Marker({
              position:latlng2,
              });
         marker2.setMap(map2);
    }


google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

If someone could help me to improve it with objects and also means would be more easier to add more maps or change `latlng` in the future. Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
function setup(el, lat, lng){
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng); //1 location
    var settings = {
        zoom: 15,
        center: latlng,
        disableDefaultUI: true,
        zoomControl: true,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById(el), settings);

    var marker=new google.maps.Marker({
        position:latlng,
    });
    marker.setMap(map);

    return marker;
}

function initialize() {
    setup('map', 48.89376, 2.33742)
    setup('map1', 40.73717, -73.98439)
    setup('map2', -8.79069, 115.15927)
}


google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/PEcNx/)

Comment: This solution is much better, and also easy to read, just wondering when do we use objects?

Comment: @olo if you need to do some actions on these `marker` objects later, you can think about classes and objects

Comment: Do we still need `var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(48.89376,2.33742); //1 location`
    `var latlng1 = new google.maps.LatLng(40.73717,-73.98439); //2 location`
    `var latlng2 = new google.maps.LatLng(-8.79069, 115.15927); //3 location` as without them it still works

Comment: @olo you can pass them also as params

Comment: Awesome! I learnt a lot from your help, will help my future coding skill :-) Thanks a million

Comment: @olo first part of code refactoring is to find out the common tasks the variable parts... then pass the variable parts as params to functions that perform the common tasks

Comment: Thanks for your explaination. Sorry, I may have too many questions, but last one,  I don't understand why do we need `return marker;`, it still works without it :-)

Comment: @olo your initialize function should be `function initialize() {
    for (i = 0; i < mapslat.length; i++) {
        setup(mapslat[i][0], mapslat[i][1], mapslat[i][2]);
    }
}`

Comment: @olo or this `function initialize() {
    for (i = 0; i < mapslat.length; i++) {
        setup.apply(window, mapslat[i]);
    }
}`

Comment: Thanks a lot both of them work like a charm. what does `(window, mapslat[i])` mean? go to grab the array from the root/beginning of the page ?

Comment: @olo read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply

Answer (score 1):

I did everything in the initialization function, but you could easily break things apart to wrap the different google map functions (i.e.. setting the markers, displaying the map, etc).  http://jsfiddle.net/tYqa9/

```
function Map(lat,long,div) {

    this.latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat,long);
    this.div = div;
    this.marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                      position:this.latlng,
                  });
    this.settings =  {
        zoom: 15,
        center: this.latlng,
        disableDefaultUI: true,
        zoomControl: true,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    this.map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById(this.div), this.settings);
    this.marker.setMap(this.map);

}



function initialize() {
    var latlng = [{lat:48.89376,lng:2.33742,div: 'Fred'},
             {lat:40.73717,lng:-73.98439,div:'George'},
             {lat:-8.79069,lng:115.15927,div:'Betty'}],
        myMap = [];
    for(i=0;i<latlng.length;i++) {
        myMap.push(new Map(latlng[i].lat,latlng[i].lng,latlng[i].div));
    }           
}


google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Comment: Many thanks for the answer. and I am learning from it. but this way doesn't work for the `div` ids are not `map`, `map1`, `map2`.. IDs are unique names like `entertainment`,`restaurant`,`workout`..

Comment: Easy change. Add the div names to the array and pass whatever you want.